# ASPNetCore - Uploading a file through REST

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman, insomnia

I am using Insomnia for testing an API, but the same happens with Postman.

I want to test a file upload, with the following controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm]IFormFile File)
```

If I set the request as a multipart request:

[image]

it works.

However, if I set it as a binary file:

[image]

I don't know how to get the data. How can it be done?

Also, in the controller method's signature, if I change [FromForm] to [FromBody], I'm not getting data.

Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: Do you have any API requirements / contract for uploading file via API? I.e. use form-data, embed file into body etc.

Comment: no, I mean it's not for a specific application: I'm trying to understand why I can send binary documents as multi-part, but not as a binary document. It's really about understand the differences in the requests, etc

Comment: OK. Let me play with this and I will get back to you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, just posted a few examples.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

As you've noticed already, using `binary file` option in Postman/Insomnia doesn't work the standard way. There are three different ways to upload file via RESTful API, and you have to choose one.

I've included code snippets that read the uploaded file contents to a string and output it -- try sending a text file, and you should get the contents of the file in the 200  response.

**Form-data upload**

This is the most popular/well-known upload method formatting the data you send as a set of key/value pairs. You normally need to specify `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data` in the request, and then use `[FromForm]` attribute in MVC to bind values to variables. Also, you can use the built-in `IFormFile` class to access the file uploaded.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostFormData([FromForm] IFormFile file)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
    {
        var content = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        return Ok(content);
    }
}
```

**Body upload**

You can send body in the format that MVC understands, e.g. JSON, and embed the file inside it. Normally, the file contents would be encoded using Base64 or other encoding to prevent character encoding/decoding issues, especially if you are sending images or binary data. E.g.

```
{
    "file": "MTIz"
}
```

And then specify `[FromBody]` inside your controller, and use class for model deserialization.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostBody([FromBody] UploadModel uploadModel)
{
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(uploadModel.File);
    var decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    return Ok(decodedString);
}
// ...
public class UploadModel
{
    public string File { get; set; }
}
```

When using large and non-text files, the JSON request becomes clunky and hard to read though.

**Binary file**

The key point here is that your file is the *whole request*. The request doesn't contain any additional info to help MVC to bind values to variables in your code. Therefore, to access the file, you need to read `Body` in the `Request`.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostBinary()
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
    {
        var body = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        return Ok(body);
    }
}
```

**Note:** the example reads `Body` as `string`. You may want to use `Stream` or `byte[]` in your application to avoid file data encoding issues.

Comment: Two days, two days I spent... Thank you.

Comment: THIS IS GOLDEN! Why this is not in official ASP.NETCORE docs ?!

Comment: This is very helpful. Which method would you recommend for uploading large binary files. Is the 3rd method (binary file) limited in file size other than the maxRequestLength?

Comment: @LazyGeek I would use #1 Form-data upload, since you can send more information like file category etc together in the same request, and it's a very common approach. 
#3 Binary file doesn't have other file size limitations than the request itself.

Comment: you are amazing

Comment: This is a superb answer, @Ignas!

Comment: superb answer 100/100

Comment: Is it best practice to use the last one for a PUT method?  That is, the user already POSTed a file and now they are replacing the contents of the resource (but the metadata is not changed, hence PUT and not DELETE followed by POST)

Comment: @Arrow_Raider I don't see how the last one would be better for one or another method. You could for example use `[FromBody]` or `[FromForm]`, and leverage the automatic model binding. 
PUT vs POST+DELETE vs PATCH is a different question about RESTful API design :)

Comment: The ReadToEndAsync() used in the Binary File example returns a string.  Is that correct? Seems like it should be byte[].  I want to be able to post a file and save it without corruption.  My ContentType is application/x-msdownload.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter you are right. This was just an oversimplified example to return the whole body in the response for testing. I've added a note. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I ended up using Request.Body.CopyToAsync( memorystream )  and it works great.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter The `Request.Body` stream doesn't allow accessing `Length`, so copying to a `MemoryStream` makes life much easier :)

Comment: removing [FromBody] and/or [FromForm] attributes has solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

In addition of the above, in case of multipart file conversion to base64String you can refer to the below:

```
if (File.Length> 0)
   {
       using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
       {
           File.CopyTo(ms);
           var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
           string s = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);                                    
       }
    }
```

**Note:** I am using this code for .NET CORE 2.1